# how to set margin for uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How to set the margin of `UITableViewCell` programmatically without creating a whole new custom cell ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to subclass `UITableViewCell` and override `layoutSubviews` method:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect tmpFrame = self.imageView.frame;
    tmpFrame.origin.x += 10;
    self.imageView.frame = tmpFrame;

    tmpFrame = self.textLabel.frame;
    tmpFrame.origin.x += 10;
    self.textLabel.frame = tmpFrame;

    tmpFrame = self.detailTextLabel.frame;
    tmpFrame.origin.x += 10;
    self.detailTextLabel.frame = tmpFrame;
}
```

Comment: that's a pretty simple and easy solution, you need to create new `UITableViewCell` subclass with this code and change your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to allocate your subclassed cells instead of regular `UITableViewCell`'s.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it just make more sense to make the UITableViewCell taller than the content to begin with? If you're content is always 100px high , just make the cell 110px to get that extra 10px space you need, No custom cell needed :)

Comment: i want the left margin to be extra 10px

Comment: well, this isn't an HTML page, you have a limited space of 320 pixels, so you just need to make sure you're using only the most right 310 pixels, so the left 10pixels are free and are used as the "spacing" .

Comment: yes I know this point, but how to set the left margin of the cell ?

Comment: ... I think i've just answered you :) You don't need to set a margin, you just position the content so there are 10 pixels on the left, and THAt is your margin.

Comment: im sorry i didn't get the idea, I can't position the content of the cell, this needs a custom cell though

Comment: Sorry, i just realized what you meant. I'm sorry to be a bearer of bad news but i think only a custom cell would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

To set the left margin you can use:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:       (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: This does not set a margin, it sets the depth of the specified row to show its hierarchical position in the section.

Comment: This solution is very clever, but it cannot be used if you want to decrease the default margin unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

Andrey has a good solution, but if you use the accessory view you need this code:

```
const int MARGIN = 16; // Left and right margin

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    /* Add left margin to the image and both labels */
    CGRect frame = self.imageView.frame;
    frame.origin.x += MARGIN;
    self.imageView.frame = frame;

    frame = self.textLabel.frame;
    frame.origin.x += MARGIN;
    frame.size.width -= 2 * MARGIN;
    self.textLabel.frame = frame;

    frame = self.detailTextLabel.frame;
    frame.origin.x += MARGIN;
    frame.size.width -= 2 * MARGIN;
    self.detailTextLabel.frame = frame;

    /* Add right margin to the accesory view */
    if (self.accessoryType != UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        float estimatedAccesoryX = MAX(self.textLabel.frame.origin.x + self.textLabel.frame.size.width, self.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.x + self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.width);

        for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
            if (subview != self.textLabel &&
                subview != self.detailTextLabel &&
                subview != self.backgroundView &&
                subview != self.contentView &&
                subview != self.selectedBackgroundView &&
                subview != self.imageView &&
                subview.frame.origin.x > estimatedAccesoryX) {

                // This subview should be the accessory, change its frame
                frame = subview.frame;
                frame.origin.x -= MARGIN;
                subview.frame = frame;
                break;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

There is no easy way to deal with the accessory view.
I've been looking for a while and this is the best solution I've seen so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This method will return the cell, you can configure cell in it. Just set the frame of the controls, move them to calculated position.

Comment: can you post a code snippet that shows how to increase the left margin (or padding-left equivalent) for the cell in this method ?